# Flash/AS3 passing a method into a method

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, methods

I am trying to make a transitionmanager and I wish to pass a method into a method, because I would like to make a bunch of different seperate transition methods which I fetch as a public static function from a Transitions class.

Example

in TransitionController class:

```
public function doTransition(mc:MovieClip, transition:Function = Transitions.Basic):void {
        transition(mc);
    }
```

in Transitions class:

```
public class Transitions
{

    public static function Basic(mc:MovieClip = null):void {
        // a whole lot of transitional stuff here
        trace("Transitions.Basic:" + mc);
    }

}
```

Does this make sense? I cant get around to get it to work

Comment: Can you post some errors as well?

Comment: never mind it went wrong somewhere else :) it works

Comment: forgot to add colons Transition.Basic()

Comment: you should probably write an answer about what the solution was and set that as the accepted answer so that this question wouldn't show up in the unanswered questions list anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind it went wrong somewhere else :) it works
forgot to add colons Transition.Basic()

Comment: you may consider closing this ticket then ; )

Comment: yeah i was doing so, but had to wait 48hrs.